# How can I test and develop my app without submitting it for review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a new social media management tool which integrates Facebook. It works sort of like postplanner.

My app helps people manage pages better.

I need posting and page management permissions to test and develop my app, but whenever I try to give these permissions to my Facebook id (who is the administrator on this app), Facebook refuses to do so, and asks me to submit it for review.

I saw the review section and it seems that the app needs to be complete to submit for review.

How can I finish my app if I can't test page posting?

I tried creating test users in Facebook, but these test users can't create test pages, and that's why I can't use them.

I don't know what's going on here... Any clues help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook gives a disclaimer above the permissions dialog, as the developer/owner of the app you don't need to heed it, you should already be able to grant yourself permissions to use it.