# My website have only login with facebook feature, can I submit it for app review?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I made a website using Django.

The only way to log into it is the facebook login.

When I had to submit my app for review in the facebook developer console. They are asking me testing id and password. Since the only way to login is facebook, and it won't work till they test.

And they are asking how to open this website for testing. It's kind of a loop.
Is there another way out?
I don't want to use other ways of logging in (is in accordance with my idea)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can test your app with your own login credentials according to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit/):

> You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used in
>   Development Mode by you or someone with a role on your app. Any
>   account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as admins,
>   developers, and testers, can use all permissions but will only be able
>   to access their own data, that of test users, and test pages belonging
>   to them.
>
> You can use any of these accounts to test your app and create a
>   screencast.

See this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935241/how-can-i-test-and-develop-my-app-without-submitting-it-for-review?rq=1).

Comment: I have tested it. Now I have to get it live. To do so, I have to submit it for app review.